# Proper way of displaying an ObservableGroupedCollection<string, TElement> using Wpf .NET 6 and the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm Package

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, community-toolkit-mvvm

## ObservableGroupedCollection in Wpf .NET 6

This question is based on:

- A **Wpf** project using **.NET 6**
- The `ObservableGroupedCollection<TKey, TElement>` class from the NuGet package **"CommunityToolkit.Mvvm"** by Microsoft
- striktly obeying the **MVVM pattern**

While tinkering with the relatively new [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-dotnet-community-toolkit-800/) I came across the `ObservableGroupedCollection<TKey, TElement>` class which in Wpf is rather undocumented. My Wpf knowledge is poor at best - I intended to use this as a learning project - and I was unable to transfer the existing UWP xaml code into a working Wpf sample application.
The sample app referenced in the blog post above uses a `CollectionViewSource` bound to an `ObservableGroupedCollection<TKey, TElement>` to display a grouped list of contacts within a scrollable control. My attempts to replicate this behavior within a Wpf .NET 6 app resulted in only the first values of each collection being displayed, rather than the entire range.

**What is the proper way to display all entries in a grouped fashion, while obeying to the MVVM pattern?!**

The following image shows an excerpt from the Microsoft Store sample application on the left and the desired result on the right.

[image: SampleApp vs Desired]

### Results from the sample code below

#### Results when iterating manually through the groups and their collections:

| **A** | **B** | **E** | **F** | **W** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a_2 | b_0 | e_0 | f_0 | w_1 |
| a_1 |  |  | f_1 | w_0 |
| a_0 |  |  | f_2 |  |

#### Values displayed in the actual ListView:

| **A** | **B** | **E** | **F** | **W** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a_2 | b_0 | e_0 | f_0 | w_1 |

[image: Displayed values] These are obviously values that got scraped off the "top" of the collections.

**What puzzles me** is the fact that the `SemanticZoom` used in the original [Sample App (.xaml - UWP)](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/blob/master/samples/MvvmSampleUwp/Views/Widgets/ContactsListWidget.xaml) and the corresponding [ViewModel.cs](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/blob/master/samples/MvvmSample.Core/ViewModels/Widgets/ContactsListWidgetViewModel.cs) is somehow able to display ALL entries instead of scraping off the first element of the collection. While still using a model based `DataTemplate`.

### Sample code

The following code is a quick and dirty example application to illustrate my problem and to provide a foundation for possible participants.

**Requirements:**

- Wpf Project -> **.NET 6**
- NuGet package: **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** by Microsoft
- 2 new folders: Models and ViewModels
- Replace all instances of ***"yourRootNamespace"*** with your actual root namespace

#### SomeModel.cs

```cs
namespace "yourRootNamespace".Models;

public class SomeModel
{

    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public SomeModel(string _s)
    {
        SomeString = _s;
    }
}
```

#### MainWindowViewModel.cs

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Collections;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using "yourRootNamespace".Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace "yourRootNamespace".ViewModels;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableGroupedCollection<string, SomeModel>? m_someObservableGroupedCollection;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        List<SomeModel> tempList = new List<SomeModel>()
        {
            new SomeModel("w_1"),
            new SomeModel("b_0"),
            new SomeModel("a_2"),
            new SomeModel("e_0"),
            new SomeModel("f_0"),
            new SomeModel("f_1"),
            new SomeModel("a_1"),
            new SomeModel("a_0"),
            new SomeModel("w_0"),
            new SomeModel("f_2")
        };

        m_someObservableGroupedCollection = new ObservableGroupedCollection<string, SomeModel>(tempList
            .GroupBy(c => char.ToUpperInvariant(c.SomeString[0]).ToString())
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key));
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
using "yourRootNamespace".ViewModels;
using System.Windows;

namespace "yourRootNamespace";

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class=""yourRootNamespace".MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:"yourRootNamespace""
        xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Collections;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Mvvm"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:"yourRootNamespace".ViewModels"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:"yourRootNamespace".Models"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Key="SomeListViewSource"
            Source="{Binding SomeObservableGroupedCollection}"
            IsLiveGroupingRequested="True"/>

        <DataTemplate
            x:Key="SomeTemplate"
            DataType="{x:Type models:SomeModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeString}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeListViewSource}, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle
                    HidesIfEmpty="True">
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate
                            DataType="{x:Type collections:IReadOnlyObservableGroup}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is difference between WPF and UWP, or i don't know where, my UI platform knowledge is poor: `CollectionViewSource` in dotnet 6 WPF does not have `IsSourceGrouped` property. Code in Microsoft samples sets this property to `true`, but your code does not - because WPF doesn't provide it.

I was getting same behavior and went to compare what's different, line by line and found the absense of `IsSourceGrouped`. The only explanation i can think of, is that grouped collection is a collection of nested collections, so internals of ListView/CollectionViewSource have to properly enumerate it in-depth, and that's what is not happening in your case.

So the answer would be: this feature is missing in a framework version you are using, so you have to resort to workarounds, and not strictly clean MVVM.

UPD: I managed to do clean xaml-only grouping with only an `ObservableCollection<T>` in ViewModel. ListView gets groups and items from a `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomViewSource}}` which controls how to group, sort and so on:

```xml
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomViewSource" Source="{Binding OnlineMods}" IsLiveGroupingRequested="True">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="YourPropertyForGrouping" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="YourPropertyForOrdering" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

It is also possible to add predefined empty groups there to be always displayed and do other tricks.

Comment: I can't try this out at the moment. As soon as I can look into it, I will reply and accept your answer! Thanks in advance, assuming that it works.

Comment: I have a WPF app in development which uses this approach. You can have a look here: https://github.com/Rast1234/SyncFaction/blob/16196b0c5d9ad90a75e3af10fe30169d4220bfc9/SyncFaction/MainWindow.xaml#L30 if you run it and press "Refresh", list is properly populated with data

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about CommunityToolkit developer's intension, it works by specifying `CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions` to `CollectionViewSource`.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SomeListViewSource"
                          Source="{Binding SomeObservableGroupedCollection}"
                          IsLiveGroupingRequested="True">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Key"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeString}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeListViewSource}, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This worked for displaying the keys as headers (thanks for that!), but the main problem remains: half of the items were wiped out by the void. In the UWP SampleApp [xaml](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/blob/master/samples/MvvmSampleUwp/Views/Widgets/ContactsListWidget.xaml) [cs](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/blob/master/samples/MvvmSample.Core/ViewModels/Widgets/ContactsListWidgetViewModel.cs), the `SemanticZoom` and the associated `ListView` is somehow able to display all values of each group instead of just the first one.